# static header with dynamic list view troubles

Tags: java, android

Similar to the contacts view on the androids contacts section, which has the search bar on top with a dynamic list view below it, [example here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24856/SO.png), I am trying to have a spinner instead of a text field.

My problem is that in the layout, the Spinner repeats per list view item.

I have the following list.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/row"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sc" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the follow Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    application = ((MyAppApplication) getApplication());
    populateOffers();
}   

private void populateOffers() 
{
    MyAppRequestor MyApp = new MyAppRequestor();
    ArrayList<String> list = MyApp.items(application.getMyAppId());

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list, R.id.rowData, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using list.xml as your layout it will be repeated.. If you want spinner only once, then you have to put in the main layout (Layout where you have defined the list view as a component.

Answer (score 0):

try this list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgd" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sc" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```